# forcing itsdangerous URLSafeTimedSerializer to give old signature

Tags: python, unit-testing

For the sake of testing I want to sign something with itsdangerous, but make it so its two days old, so it will show up as expired in testing.  Is there a way you can do this?

Comment: Why not mock the calls to itsdangerous and just raise the exception in the mock? You are not testing itsdangerous code, you are testing your own code.

Comment: good point, I'm still getting used to mock.  Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try and trick `itsdangerous` into specific behaviour. Use a mock instead, and have it return values or raise exceptions exactly as you need it to for you to test *your own code*.

For example, using the [`.loads()` method](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/#itsdangerous.TimedSerializer.loads) with an expired value, results in the [`SignatureExpired` exception](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/#itsdangerous.SignatureExpired) being raised. Using the [`mock` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) mock could simply do the same.

I'd expect your code to look something like this:

```
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer

def some_function(signed_value):
    result = URLSafeTimedSerializer(secret).loads(signed_value, max_age=3600)
```

You can mock out the `URLSafeTimedSerializer` class, and make the call to the `.loads()` method raise the same exception. In addition, you can then make assertions as to what arguments were passed in by your code-under-test:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch
from itsdangerous import SignatureExpired

import module_under_test

class ModuleTests(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('module_under_test.URLSafeTimedSerializer')
    def test_expired_signature(self, serializer_mock):
        instance = serializer_mock.return_value  # what is returned when the mock is called
        instance.loads.side_effect = SignatureExpired

        with self.assertRaises(SignatureExpired):
            module_under_test.some_function('foo_bar')

        serializer_mock.assert_called_with('your_test_secret')
        instance.loads.assert_called_with('foo_bar', max_age=3600)
```